# Css Table-cell and relative width

Tags: css, display, tablecell

I'm struggling with a CSS issue and I was hoping for some help.

Here's the story:
I'm designing a header. It's split in two divs. First one must be 70% wide and second one 30% wide. I used the css-property "Display: table-cell" in order to place them side by side.

```
div.chapo {
width: 70%;
display: table-cell;
}

div.img_header {
width: 30%;
display: table-cell;
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
background-image: url(...);
}
```

It's working fine when the text placed in the first div is long enough:

[image: ok]

Buuuut... when text is short, it's all messy:

[image: notok]

I can't figure out why my widths values aren't kept in this specific case.
Thanks in advance for all who would be kind enough to help me...

Here's the fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/vinny38/verucw8p/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrapped both div `ce_text chapo` and `img_header` to `.test-wrap` class and give it to below css:

```
.test-wrap {
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```css
body,
div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto condensed', sans-serif;
}

div.inside {
  position: relative;
}

div.chapo {
  background-color: #ef4056;
  background-image: none;
  width: 70%;
  height: 255px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: #aaa;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px 8%;
  position: relative;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
  font: 1.4em 'Oswald', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

div.chapo p {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 300;
}

div.img_header {
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-image: url(https://image.freepik.com/free-psd/abstract-background-design_1297-73.jpg);
}

div.mod_breadcrumb {
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
  padding-left: 8%;
}

.mod_breadcrumb ul li {
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 0;
  color: #828282;
}
.test-wrap {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="inside">
  <div class="test-wrap">
    <div class="ce_text chapo">
      <h1>My header</h1>
      <div class='text-chapo'>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="img_header"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="mod_breadcrumb block">
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just perfect! Thanks ^^

Answer (score 0):

This CSS it's ok... the 'float:left' option and relative width are different.
 Here, I disccount the paddings left and right of total width. The float is necessary to horizontal align.

```
body,
div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto condensed', sans-serif;

}

div.inside {
  position: relative;
}

div.chapo {
      background-image: none;
    width: 50%;
    height: 255px;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: #aaa;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px 10%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;

}

h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
  font: 1.4em 'Oswald', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

div.chapo p {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 300;
}

div.img_header {
     width: 30%;
    position: relative;
    height: 295px;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    float: left;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(https://image.freepik.com/free-psd/abstract-background-design_1297-73.jpg);
}

div.mod_breadcrumb {
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
  padding-left: 8%;
  float:left;
  width:90%;
}

.mod_breadcrumb ul li {
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 0;
  color: #828282;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:
You have to define `float` property as well as you must define `height:255px`  (as for another div you have given height as 255px )for your `img_header` class. It's really necessary.

```css
body,
div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto condensed', sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

div.inside {
  position: relative;
}

div.chapo {
  background-color: #ef4056;
  background-image: none;
  width: 70%;
  float:left;
  height: 255px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: #aaa;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px 8%;
  position: relative;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
  font: 1.4em 'Oswald', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

div.chapo p {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.clearfix {
  clear:both;
}
.img_header {
  width: 30%;
height: 255px;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-image: url(https://image.freepik.com/free-psd/abstract-background-design_1297-73.jpg);
}

div.mod_breadcrumb {
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
  padding-left: 8%;
}

.mod_breadcrumb ul li {
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 0;
  color: #828282;
}
```

```html
<div class="inside">
  <div class="ce_text chapo">
    
    <div class='text-chapo'>
    <h1>My header</h1>
      <p>Lorem </p>
      <p>Aliquam porttitor.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="img_header"></div>
  
  <div class="mod_breadcrumb block">
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```